# Python Regex recurring non-capture group

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
12/27/2016 08:05 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator A (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/26/2016 08:06 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator B (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/23/2016 08:06 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator C (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/22/2016 08:05 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator A (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/22/2016 12:57 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator B (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/21/2016 02:03 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator C (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n'
```

As you can see, if features the repeated phrase:

```
12/27/2016 08:05 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator A/B/C (PID-000301): ...
```

I would like to clean this up, by writing a regex which picks up this recurring phrase and the deletes it. I have written something like that so far:

```
r'(?:\n?\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d.+\(PID-\d{6}\):)+([\w\W]+)'
```

However, that only removes the first occurrence of the repeated phrase. How do I "loop" it over, so that it picks up all instances?

Comment: Have you tried using the flag [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sz5TVQ/2):

```
import re

s = '12/27/2016 08:05 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator A (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/26/2016 08:06 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator B (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/23/2016 08:06 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator C (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/22/2016 08:05 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator A (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/22/2016 12:57 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator B (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n*************************************************************************************************\r\n12/21/2016 02:03 AM (GMT+01:00) added by Operator C (PID-000301):\r\nOthers/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade\r\n\r\n'

s = re.sub(r'\s*\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.+\(PID-\d{6}\):', '', s)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Others/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade

*************************************************************************************************
Others/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade

*************************************************************************************************
Others/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade

*************************************************************************************************
Others/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade

*************************************************************************************************
Others/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade

*************************************************************************************************
Others/Malfunction;Device failure not specified;It Crasched during upgrade
```